# Rebuild reporting database. Exception Message: String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: xdb, indexing

Sitecore 8.0 update 5

I've set up clean `sitecore.analytics` and `sitecore.analytics_secondary` databases.

Also I've deployed the Marketing Definitions and ran necessary SQL script to copy data from old to new reporting databases. Mongo collections have been downloaded from live site.

During the rebuilding reporting database I have a lot of errors like

> ERROR Exception when storing an aggregation result into reporting database. Item will be postponed and retried later.
>   Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   Message: String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>   Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider.Commit(SqlDataApi api, IReportingStorageItemBatch batch, Func`2 filter)
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__1()
>      at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.ExecuteNoResult(Action action, Action recover)
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider.StoreBatch(IReportingStorageItemBatch batch)
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider.Store(IReportingStorageItemBatch batch)

I've already tried `Sitecore.Support` fix number **97934**.

What can be the reason of these errors?

**EDIT 1**

Like I mentioned in question I've set up new sitecore instance and get mongo data and sitecore items package from live. So when I deploy Deploy Marketing Definitions on my new reporting database, segments has Deployed Date > Interaction date time. I've found an post about it.

> Segments are used while aggregating the data for the Experience
>   Analytics application. If the interaction.SaveDateTime <=
>   segment.DeployDate, the interaction won't be aggregated (That's why we
>   need to change the deploy date manually).

https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/9/t/1028

it help me to get rid of part of mistakes. But I still have a couple of these errors in logs.